# Как правильно заполнять keywords?

Tags: html, seo, key

По одному слову или фразами, и что будет, если заполнять фразами (если неправильно, как я предполагаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте исходный код любого сайта, например, ХэшКода

```
<meta name="keywords" content="вопросы, ответы, программирование, c, c++, c#, java, javascript, php, python, ruby, go, perl" />
```

Как видите, ключевые слова (и фразы тоже) пишут через запятую.

Comment: Открыл код Хэшкода этой же страницы и слегка удивился
<meta name="keywords" content="seo html google yandex key" />

Answer (score 1):

ТС'у минус походу умник поставил?

[[@inferus-vv](/users/6278/inferus-vv)](/users/6278/inferus-vv) идем в гугл и вводим:

- **низкочастотные запросы**
- **среднечастотные запросы**
- **высокочастотные запросы**

читаете информацию, узнаете длину запросов по количеству слов для каждого и составляем ключевики через запятую!

Хорошо если вы ключевики будите  чередовать а не писать сразу по слову, потом по два, три и т.д. хотя не факт что это уже имеет вес!

Добавлю что для пс сейчас важен title и h1 на странице, раньше конечно же большую роль играли ключевики.

- составьте **семантическое ядро сайта**
- составьте ключевики
- пропишите верно дескрипшены
- грамотная **внутренняя перелинковка страниц**
- если уместно, добавьте кнопки мне
     нравится из соц сетей
- зарегистрируйте сайт в нескольких
     крупных каталогах

для первичного продвижения, этого довольно достаточно! подождите месяц, посмотрите на результат, на каких позициях находится сайт в пс по составленным вами ключевым запросам!

З.Ы. Продвижение сайта это очень кропотливая работа, на которую уходят месяцы!
З.Ы.Ы. для того продвинуть сайт в топ 10, 5, 3 нужно очень много читать инфы на эту тему!

троекратное З.Ы. важные слова для сёрча я отметил жирным!